# Change status code for a specific Exception in middleware

Tags: asp.net, http, error-handling, middleware, http-status-code-401

I have ASP.NET application with JWTMiddleware. At certain times (not predicatable), the token gets expired throwing SecurityTokenExpiredException and hence throwing 500. What we want is to have a control over the returned status code, returning 401 (instead of 500) and throw the exception received.
I tried writing a middleware (set it up after my JwtTokenMiddleware). Inside the middleware I'm just catching the relevant exception type and changing the context.Response.StatusCode to 401, but on the client I am still receiving 500. Any clues ?

Comment: Try placing your middleware **before** the `JwtTokenMiddleware`.

Comment: This is how code looks like:
 app.UseMiddleware<ReliabilityMiddleWare>();

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Audience = audience;
                options.Authority = authority;
                options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
                options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudiences = audiences.Select(t => t.Value)
                };
            });placing it before yielding same results @peco

Comment: public class ReliabilityMiddleWare
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ReliabilityMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;

                throw ex;
            
            }
        }